# javascript create image from text using fonts, background and text colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have been looking high and low for a Javascript framework or any JS code that will allow me to create an JPG or PNG image on the fly, but I can't seem to find any.  I need to create an image using a selected background color, user entered text words, a selected font and then a selected text color.  Once the image is created I then need add it the current HTML form page, and then pass the image to my server when the form is submitted.  But all I am finding is stuff to manipulate an existing image, so is my request even possible?

I know I can create an image and append it to and existing page using something like the following:

```
$('#container').append($('<img>', { 
    src : "/path/to/image.jpg", 
    width : 16, 
    height : 16, 
    alt : "Test Image", 
    title : "Test Image"
}));
```

Or....

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'my_image.jpg';
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(img);
```

But both of those options requiring using an existing image....I need to be able to completely create a new image from scratch.

Comment: You probably want a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) - see plenty of SO questions on how to convert to an image.

Comment: @freedomn-m - thanks.  I have not heard of the canvas object before.  All my reading did not turn that up.  I don't understand why this was down voted twice.  Its a legit question -  people down vote things because they assume I should know something (like `canvas`), but obviously posting the question implies that I do not.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple example of drawing to a hidden canvas, then copying the resulting image data to an image element. Once this element is created it can be copied, saved etc.

A useful resource for the Canvas API is here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

And a tutorial is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial

```js
function drawHelloWorld(canvas) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    // Draw the background
    ctx.rect(0, 0, 250, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fill();
 
    // Draw the text
    ctx.font = "30px Helvetica";
    ctx.fillStyle = "ghostwhite";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World", 50, 60);
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
drawHelloWorld(canvas);

const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
imgElement.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(imgElement);
```

```html
<canvas hidden id="myCanvas" width="250" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Double Thanks!  I had no idea `canvas` existed until this post.  All my google searches brought up image manipulators or create an image from an existing image.

Comment: Hopefully this will get you a little further with your project!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new image from scratch by using JavaScript Canvas.

Something like this:

```
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
<script>
     window.onload = function() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // This fills the background
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

        // Add text with spesific font
        ctx.font = 'bold 48px serif';
        ctx.strokeText('Made on Fly!', 50, 100);

        // Make canvas to data URI
        const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        // Here you can convert dataUrl to base64 and use it for other purposes

        const aDoc = document.createElement("a");
        aDoc.href = dataUrl;
        aDoc.download = "Made_on_fly.png";
        document.body.appendChild(aDoc);
        // Make a element click for download
        aDoc.click();
     }
</script>
```

Comment: THANKS!  Once @freedomn-m commented to the OP about `canvas` I quickly looked it up and see that it is exactly what I am looking for.  I had no idea this existed.

Answer (score 0):

Image can be represented as `base64` encoded Data URL, so you can generate this URL and use it.

Example usage:

```js
// Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/8/14
import React from "react";

function textToImageDataUrl(text: string): string {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 320 * 4;
    canvas.height = 180 * 4;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d")!;
    context.rect(0, 0, 320 * 4, 180 * 4);
    context.fillStyle = "indigo";
    context.fill();
    context.font = "256px Consolas, Sans Serif";
    context.fillStyle = "orange";
    context.fillText(text, 80 * 4, 110 * 4);
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

const TextImage: React.FC<{ text: string }> = ({text}) => {
    return <img alt="" src={textToImageDataUrl(text)}/>
}
```